# Keyboard Shortcut: Only half of MCE R6 buttons work

Tags: shortcut-keys, remote

I've just installed Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, on a desktop PC. I'm using this computer as a media/gaming PC.   I have a Harmony 350 Control IR (MCE R6) remote that is used primarily to control the media application, however I would like to use some of the buttons on the remote to launch applications and otherwise control the PC.

I'm mapping buttons to commands using the System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts menu.   I've used the /lib/udev/keymaps/rc6_mce file and put it in /etc/rc_keymaps

Most of the buttons work. For example, I have mapped the "Media" button to start Spotify by mapping my remote's "Audio Media" button to launch it.

[Successfully mapped to Media](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uYdR.png)

But I can't map my remote's INFO button to launch Kodi. When I go to assign it, the Keyboard Mapping application doesn't 'see' it.  I've held it down for awhile, but nothing happens.

Both keys are in the /etc/rc_keymaps/rc6_mce file:

```
0x800f040d KEY_MEDIA
0x800f040f KEY_INFO
```

And when I use ir-keytable -t, both work as expected, so the computer is receiving them:

```
1515875517.689915: event type EV_MSC(0x04): scancode = 0x800f040d
1515875517.689915: event type EV_KEY(0x01) key_down: KEY_MEDIA(0x00e2)
1515875517.689915: event type EV_SYN(0x00).
1515875517.964577: event type EV_KEY(0x01) key_up: KEY_MEDIA(0x00e2)
1515875517.964577: event type EV_SYN(0x00).
1515875518.928910: event type EV_MSC(0x04): scancode = 0x800f040f
1515875518.928910: event type EV_KEY(0x01) key_down: KEY_INFO(0x0166)
1515875518.928910: event type EV_SYN(0x00).
1515875519.212562: event type EV_KEY(0x01) key_up: KEY_INFO(0x0166)
1515875519.212562: event type EV_SYN(0x00).
```

But when trying to map them, the Keyboard Shortcut application will only see KEY_MEDIA.

And, again, this isn't just these two buttons. These two are just good examples because they're so similar.  Lots of other buttons work (FastForwrd, Rewind, Record, etc) and lots don't (The entire numberpad, menu, guide, etc) with the same issue.  ir-keytable sees them fine, but the Keyboard Settings application doesn't.

So, what is there between ir-keytable and the keyboard shortcut app that is 'eating' my button presses?

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for terminal text. Instead, paste the text into your question, select the text with your mouse, and press the `{}` button in the editor.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out.

X11 only understands scan-codes up to 255.   Half of the buttons on the remote use higher scancodes. So, I first got a list of all the scancodes my remote uses by doing:

**ir-keytable --read --device=/dev/input/event19**

(/dev/input/event19 is the device my remote is on.  Running ir-keytable with no parameters will tell you which one yours is.)

That produces a list like this. The number at the end in brackets is what we're interested in.

```
scancode 0x800f0410 = KEY_VOLUMEUP (0x73)
scancode 0x800f0411 = KEY_VOLUMEDOWN (0x72)
scancode 0x800f0412 = KEY_CHANNELUP (0x192)
scancode 0x800f0413 = KEY_CHANNELDOWN (0x193)
scancode 0x800f0414 = KEY_FASTFORWARD (0xd0)
```

Anything in that list larger than 0xFF won't work. (Or, simpler said, anything that has three digits. So CHANNELUP (0x192) and CHANNELDOWN (0x193) in this case)

Then I just edited my /etc/rc_keymaps/rc6_mce file and mapped those buttons to something I knew was lower.

This also solved an issue I had with Kodi where some buttons weren't working on my remote.  KEY_INFO, KEY_STOP and some others.  I remapped those to regular key presses (KEY_INFO to KEY_I, etc) and that works as well now.